# Openstack spontaneous mysql connection error 2006, "MySQL server has gone away

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, openstack

I am running openstack `queens` on openstack-ansible deployment, Recently i found in lots multiple components like nova & neutron started throwing following error stack in logs, everything working fine but that error make me worry, does anyone know anything about this?

I have check basic thing like F5 LB, MySQL, network connectivity all looks good.

```
2018-08-13 10:36:23.552 17533 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.engines "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
2018-08-13 10:36:23.552 17533 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.engines DBConnectionError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))") [SQL: u'SELECT 1'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
2018-08-13 10:36:34.997 17538 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.engines [req-c9a4ea4f-3577-42c7-aed3-e34416d93c1a 34205a21a4e4430b8be896c6a6b692cb 2b1447ec414b4751965f75785cab6468 - default default] Database connection was found disconnected; reconnecting: DBConnectionError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))") [SQL: u'SELECT 1'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
2018-08-13 10:36:34.997 17538 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.engines "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
2018-08-13 10:36:34.997 17538 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.engines DBConnectionError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))") [SQL: u'SELECT 1'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
2018-08-13 10:38:23.231 17529 ERROR oslo_db.sqlalchemy.engines [req-ba38ec9d-ee4e-4974-933b-46c8133397c1 34205a21a4e4430b8be896c6a6b692cb 2b1447ec414b4751965f75785cab6468 - default default] Database connection was found disconnected; reconnecting: DBConnectionError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))") [SQL: u'SELECT 1'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Here you can see more logs: http://paste.openstack.org/show/728277/

This is my 3 node Galera cluster setting.

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
[mysqld_safe]
socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
nice = 0
log_error = /var/log/mysql_logs/galera_server_error.log
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8
[mysqld]
user = mysql
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
bind-address = ::
server-id = 200
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 0
slow-query-log = 0
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql_logs/mysql-slow.log
log_error = /var/log/mysql_logs/galera_server_error.log
log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mariadb-bin
log-bin-index = /var/lib/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
expire-logs-days = 7
log_slave_updates = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
max-allowed-packet = 16M
max-connect-errors = 1000000
max_connections = 1600
wait_timeout = 3600
tmp-table-size = 32M
max-heap-table-size = 32M
query-cache-type = 0
query-cache-size = 0M
thread-cache-size = 50
open-files-limit = 65535
table-definition-cache = 4096
table-open-cache = 10240
innodb-flush-method = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-file-size = 1024M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size = 4096M
innodb-read-io-threads = 4
innodb-write-io-threads = 4
innodb-doublewrite = 1
innodb-log-buffer-size = 128M
innodb-buffer-pool-instances = 8
innodb-log-files-in-group = 2
innodb-thread-concurrency = 64
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 16M
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of reasons that you can get the "Server has gone away" message.  Too many to paste in. Read this over and see if any apply to you:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html

When I've encountered these situations in the past,

- there is a firewall in between the app server and database, that closes the tcp session
- there's a stale connection in the connection pool
- admin has killed connection on the server and the app doesn't report it until using the connection again.

If connection pooling is used, make sure the connection lifetime (or timeout, etc) is less than your configured `wait_timeout`.

Since the query that fails is `SELECT 1` I assume that the connection pool has connection validation enabled.  This checks the connection with a simple query and if it fails, it uses a new connection from the pool, and tries again.  This looks like normal operation to handle lost connections.

***Edit***

Since you found out that the F5 had a short timeout, that can be increased to something more realistic for database connections.  I've seen anywhere from 1 to 8 hours depending if it's an application connection, or coming from a desktop app.

To force your client to refresh it's connections, with SQLAlchemy, it  looks like pool_recycle is what you would want to add, to recycle connections before F5 timeout.  Wherever the DataSource is being defined in OpenStack- that's where to you need to add more config options for SQLAlchemy docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html.

However, I would just update the F5/HAProxy to 1 hour and see how how frequently you get these errors.

Comment: Client and servers all are in same LAN and we have no firewall there, i will look into `wat_timeout` but i am sure its high enough. related `SELECT 1` do you think this is normal if connection failed?

Comment: @Satish Depending on how your connection pooling is configured, `SELECT 1` is executed every time a connection is pulled form your connection pool.  If you only see this error on `SELECT 1` then I wouldn't be too concerned, as the connection validation is doing its job.  Of course, there may be some measurable overhead to validating connections.

Comment: This is interesting, My galera cluster running behind `F5` load-balancer, when i replace F5 load-balancer with `haproxy` LB error disappeared, This is odd.. I have check everything single thing and F5 LB working fine nothing wrong i did some test with `mysql` cli client and everything looks good they this python application doesn't like F5?

Comment: It appears that the F5 was closing the connections.  Double check timeouts there and find out if it logs information when it closes sessions (just to validate what's happening).  Otherwise, you can change the client side connection pool to recycle connections at an aggressive rate (to test the timeout theroy)   https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/config-reference/common-configurations/database.html http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Comment: finally i changed F5 `SNAT` profile `fastL4`  `idle_timeout` from 300 second to `3600` second which fixed issue, but openstack using `oslo` db backend how do i know its idle_timeout or default timeout, in nova.conf i didn't find any setting.

Comment: I've never used OpenStack :(. Wherever the DataSource is being defined - that's where to you need to add more config options for SQLAlchemy http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html.  It looks like `pool_recycle` is what you would want to add, to recycle connections before F5 timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, put that stuff in answer and i will accept it :)